# Using FindControl to get GridView in a Content Page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, master-pages, findcontrol

I would like to find a `GridView` Control within a separate class and I am having issues doing so. I even tried placing my code in the aspx.cs page to no avail. I keep getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I'm sure there is a simple step I'm missing, but in my research I cannot seem to find anything.

### Aspx code

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" EnableViewState="true" 
    runat="server"  
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" Width="933px" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  
    onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
    onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"
    onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting"
    AllowSorting="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    PersistedSelection="true" onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
    <EditRowStyle Font-Size="Small" Width="100px" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="EditLinkButton" CausesValidation="True"
                          Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"/>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteLinkButton" CausesValidation="False"
                          Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="UpdateLinkButton" CausesValidation="True"
                          Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="CancelLinkButton" CausesValidation="False"
                          Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>
        </EditItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

### .cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  SetDirectory();

  System.Web.UI.Page page = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler;
  GridView GridViewCopy = (GridView)page.FindControl("GridView1");

  Log.WriteLine("SortBindGrid: GridView Row Count: " + 
                GridViewCopy.Rows.Count, Log.DEBUG_LEVEL.TERSE);
  return;
}
```

I've tried a few variations of using MainContent_GridView for the find to get and Master.FindControl with all the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one of your comments you state that the `GridView` isn't on the Master Page, so is it safe to assume that it's on a page that uses a Master Page? And therefore it must be in a `ContentPlaceholder` control?

The key issue is that `FindControl` method [only looks for direct children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) (emphasis added):

> This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, **the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls**.

So you either need to:

1. Search for the control within the correct `ContentPlaceholder` control, rather than from `Page`.
2. Loop through each of the Controls in `Page.Controls` recursively until you find the control you're after.

An example of 2:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = 
            FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Once you've got your control, you should cast it using `as` and then check for null just in case it's not quite what you were expecting:

```
var gridView = FindControlRecursively(Page, "GridView1") as GridView

if (null != gridView) {
  // Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: ok I will give all of this a whirl Ben. Thank you. The reason I mentioned MasterPage is because Ihave run into issues before where if there is a MasterPage involved (even if the control is not inside the site.master) there are changes in what you need to look for (ie. MainContent_controID) Thanks again I'll post how it goes

Comment: Thank you everyone for your ideas and answers. code public static string GetControlName() { string controlName = ""; Control control = null; try { System.Web.UI.Page currentPage = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler; control = currentPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("GridView1"); controlName = control.ClientID; } catch (Exception ex) { } return controlName; }

Answer (score 0):

Don't get the page from HttpContext if you are already within the page.  Instead, is there a control you can use FindControl from?  Instead of use page, use:

```
parentControl.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
```

Instead.  There is an issue with finding the grid from the page level, and using a lower level control closer to the grid will have better success.

Comment: @HTH I am guess you meant to Cast the right sidee to of type gris like this Grid   GridView grid = (GridView)this.Master.FindControl("GridView1");  This did not work. are you sure you have to set an interface for it? seems kind of more than should be needed

Comment: Also, not sure if I mentioned this, but the Grid is not part of the master page, but I know that theings have to be accessed differently when using a sitemaster

Comment: Oh well then that changes everything.  I thought it was in the master page.

Comment: Brian- what would be the parentcontrol if the gridview is at the top? Do I have to put this in a panel for it to work?

Comment: Sure, for testing purposes, try wrapping it with an <asp:Panel id="P1" runat="server"> and try using P1.FindControl("GridView1") and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your ideas and answers. `code public static string GetControlName() { string controlName = ""; Control control = null; try { System.Web.UI.Page currentPage = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler; control = currentPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("GridView1"); controlName = control.ClientID; } catch (Exception ex) { } return controlName; }`

Answer (score 0):

Brian got it right but he forgot the essential part.
You won't be able to do use his code unless you add this code on top of your HTML-Code of the file where you want to use it.(Page.aspx)

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master/Site.master" %>
```

then you can use the code Brian suggested:

```
GridView grid = this.Master.FindControl("GridView1");
```

---

Edit:
If you want to use the gridview from within another class in the same file i would use the following:
Add this to the class created when you make the page

```
 public partial class YourPageName: System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    public static Gridview mygrid = this.GridviewnameOFYourASPX
    ...
 }
```

And to your custom class add this in your method

```
YourPageName.mygrid.(The changes you want to make);
```

Comment: I must be missing something here. GridView grid = this.Master.FindControl("GridView1");  Yields the Error  Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'. An explicit conversion exists I'm not sure how the above MasterType code will fix that?
 Also, I tried adding the MasterType in there and still does not work. I have a GridView Control that exists in Newpage.aspx, but have a Site.Master page. I want to access this GridView from within another generic class file that is in the same project. Can this be done? and if so how.

Comment: FindControl returns a Control, which can't be assigned to a GridView variable.  That is the error.  However, if you aren't finding a control in the master page, you can't use the Master property.

Comment: Is this what you wanted?
Brian:
You can do it normaly by doing ((GridView)this.Master.FindControl("GridView1")).Something();

Comment: The class I'm looking to access the control with a class that is in the same project but NOT the same file. It is a single .cs file, not aspx.cs. Will this still work bejee. Also the grid is Not in the site.master file. I was just mentioning that I have a master file... Do I still need to do a .master if it isn't in the master page?

Comment: @Beejee, what I meant was, he said in a comment to my post, that the control isn't in the master page.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your ideas and answers. End result proof of concept code : code public static string GetControlName() { string controlName = ""; Control control = null; try { System.Web.UI.Page currentPage = (System.Web.UI.Page)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler; control = currentPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent").FindControl("GridView1"); controlName = control.ClientID; } catch (Exception ex) { } return controlName; }