# Retrieving values from selected row gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have some data binded to gridview and wanted to know if it is possible to retrieve the values in a selected row and insert those values into a series of textboxes or labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use the `FindControl` method

- [here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12021/Accessing-the-different-controls-inside-a-GridView)

Duplicates

- [How to find control in TemplateField of GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview)
- [Using FindControl to get GridView in a Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525804/using-findcontrol-to-get-gridview-in-a-content-page)

Comment: So does FindControl actually find the individual values of each cell of the gridview?

Comment: You can use it on the row or on the cell. e.g. `row.FindControl("controlID")` or `row.Cells[0].FindControl("coontrolID")`. Get the control `TextBox txtName = (TextBox) row.FindContro("txtName")`

Comment: To find cell value, I think it is `row.Cells[0].Text`. Please check to verify

Answer (score 0):

As @codingbiz said: You can use `FindControl` and `TemplateField`.

The example:

EditGridView.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditGridView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Q11874496WebApp.EditGridView" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="Id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Lblname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LblPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    &nbsp;Id:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;Phone:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" OnClick="BtnUpdate_Click" Text="Update" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EditGridView.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class EditGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (this.MyDataList.Count == 0)
            {
                this.populateData();
            }
            this.GridView1.DataSource = this.MyDataList;
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data for the GridView. Encapsulates a list that will be in session.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<MyDataPoco> MyDataList
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Session["MyDataList"] == null)
                this.Session["MyDataList"] = new List<MyDataPoco>();
            return (IList<MyDataPoco>)this.Session["MyDataList"];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a list of 10 items.
    /// </summary>
    private void populateData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            this.MyDataList.Add(
                new MyDataPoco()
                {
                    Id = i.ToString(),
                    Name = "Name " + i,
                    Phone = i + "" + i + "" + i + "." + i + "" + i + "" + i + "" + i + ""
                });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Here is the way you can get values from GridView.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = this.GridView1.SelectedRow;
        Label LblId = (Label)row.FindControl("LblId");
        Label LblName = (Label)row.FindControl("LblName");
        Label LblPhone = (Label)row.FindControl("LblPhone");

        this.TxtId.Text = LblId.Text;
        this.TxtName.Text = LblName.Text;
        this.TxtPhone.Text = LblPhone.Text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the data in the GridView.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.GridView1.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
                this.GetType(),
                "alert",
                "alert('Select before...');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            MyDataPoco myDateItem = this.MyDataList[this.GridView1.SelectedIndex];
            myDateItem.Id = this.TxtId.Text;
            myDateItem.Name = this.TxtName.Text;
            myDateItem.Phone = this.TxtPhone.Text;

            this.GridView1.DataSource = this.MyDataList;
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

MyDataPoco.cs:

```
public class MyDataPoco
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Complete source : [Q11874496WebApp.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11874496WebApp.7z)